# Unable to reset default from Rhythmbox to Banshee since 12.04

Tags: 12.04, banshee, rhythmbox

Since 12.04 update when I click on my favorite radio on this page http://www.originalsamplesloops-and-music-online.com/musique.informatique/les_radios_de_la_guadeloupe.html it no longer works when I click on "Radio Rbi Fm Guadeloupe **Ecouter**".
It used to be I clicked on "Ecouter" and the music would play in Banshee. Now a window opens and I can only choose "open with" "Rhythmbox (Standard)" or "Rbi-fm 10.pls", neither of which plays the music! The third choice, "Other..." is useless because clicking it does not bring up a list of programs to choose from!

I clicked on Gearwheel in top right corner > System settings > "Banshee" as default for music. Shut down computer and restarted. Still Radio Rbi will not play in Banshee.

Also there is a brief, funny sound from my speakers whenever I load that page in Firefox (and intermittently afterwards), sounds like door chimes or like the Windows "can't do this" sound.

Please help!

Comment: This is a bug in Ubuntu trackable here: [lp:#876897](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/876897), and so is off topic here. Hopefully this will be resolved in a stable release update down the line.

Comment: @Jacob I can't make heads or tails of that page, do you have practical advice for me that I can use right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding Radio directly to Rhythmbox.

Hare is how!

Save the .pls file.[image]

Open it with text editor and copy the URL.
[image]

Open Rhythmbox. and add new Radio.[image]

Paste the URL hare and click add.

[image]

That's it. You can now play your Radio directly from Rhythmbox. You can add more online Radios like this.

Comment: Thank you! A practical work-around, with very helpful screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

For use from the browser you can set 1 app as the default easily

Could have you edit .local/share/applications/mimeapps.list but this is easier.

Right click on the desktop & create a new document. Name it `1.pls` Then right click on 1.pls > Properties > Open with. Choose the app you wish & click 'Set as Default' button

You can then delete 1.pls

The other thing you can do from than site is actually just download the Rbi-Fm.pls, save it somewhere & right click > open with any suitable player